# Why I cannot connect to PostgreSQL through PHP and bash script?

Tags: php, bash, psql

I am using MAPP to run PHP pages with PostgreSQL Database.

Through mac terminal I use this command to create the database:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE "newDBTest";"
```

and it works great.

Now, I need to create a database through bash script and PHP.
here the php page code:

```
<body>
<?php

$contents = file_get_contents('testDB.sh');
$output = null;
$return_var = null;
$contents = escapeshellarg($contents);
exec("/usr/local/bin/bash -c $contents 2>&1 & echo $!", $output, $return_var);
echo "<hr>";
print_r($contents);
echo "<hr>";
print_r($return_var);
echo "<hr>";
print_r($output);
echo "<hr>";   
?>   
</body>
```

Here the bash script file:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash


PATH="/usr/local/bin/psql:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"


PGUSER=postgres
PGPASSWORD=password
PGDATABASE=newDBFromBashPHP
PGHOST=127.0.0.1
PGPORT=5432

echo "host: $PGHOST"
which psql

psql -h $PGHOST -p $PGPORT -U $PGUSER -c '\l'
echo "Dropping DB... $PGDATABASE"
psql -h $PGHOST -p $PGPORT -U $PGUSER -c "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS \"${PGDATABASE}\";"
echo "Creating DB... $PGDATABASE"
psql -h $PGHOST -p $PGPORT -U $PGUSER -c "CREATE DATABASE \"${PGDATABASE}\";"
```

When I run the php page, I got this error for each of the psql commands above

```
psql.bin: error: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL: database "newDBFromBashPHP" does not exist
```

It even refuse to connect and show at least the list of available databases.
However, if use one of existing databases that created previously through the terminal in the variable `PGDATABASE`, it works perfect without any errors.

My question, why I got this error? I know the DB is not exist and I want to create it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a password problem. Try to use a connection string instead like

`psql postgresql://user:password@host:port`